# Swift UITextView and UIImageView UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I'm working with Swift, setting up a UITextView created in IB, attempting to get multiple images on the page to wrap text programmatically. Seems to work fine with one image path but breaks (stops wrapping the first image) when I add a 2nd image. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Code example:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "testimage"))
    image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, image.frame.width, image.frame.height))
    textContainer.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [path]
    textContainer.addSubview(image)

    let image2 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "testimage2"))
    image2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
    let path2 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(100, 200, image.frame.width, image.frame.height))
    textContainer.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [path2]
    textContainer.addSubview(image2)
```

Thank you!

Dorian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the second path to the `exclusionPaths` array.

At the moment you are replacing the first path with the second instead of using both.

For example:

`textContainer.textContainer.exclusionPaths.append(path2)`